# Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to implement Google Maps in my application, so I tried this 
[Google Maps v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2)

but when I take this code:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I get this error:

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/
>    google_play_services_version').

I have

- imported the google-play-services.jar
- updated everything in the SDK Manager

after all it still doesn't work, I imported libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\version.xml to my project

this error is away but if I run the project on my device the logcat shows this error message

> 12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{#############.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4499)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2007)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at #########.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4637)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1051)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    ... 11 more
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:581)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:549)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4407)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    ... 20 more
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:571)
>   12-28 17:22:29.850: E/AndroidRuntime(28040):    ... 23 more

I have my own API Key and the name of the package is correct. 
Maybe there is some problem with my eclipse or the android sdk!?

Comment: Tell me what you see after right clicking the project, properties and go to android. In the second frame(is library), is there a green right mark or red x mark? - ofcourse it is assuming that you have added the google-play-services library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After importing the *google-play-services* project, you have to add this library project to your application like this-

right click the project --> properties --> Android --> Add --> select google-play-services --> Ok --> Apply --> Ok

Comment: i have imported the project but there was a red x (I have overlooked it -.-) 
thank you so much!!! i was so mad, i made a stackoverflow account :D

Comment: You have to put your project and google-play-services project in same work space. Make sure it.

Answer (score 0):

How have you imported it? You have to add `google-play-services` as a library to your project.

Comment: right click the project --> properties --> java build path --> libraries --> add external jars...

Comment: right click -> properties -> android -> Libray section -> add (selct google_play services, which has to be imported to your workspace before)